# how could you only email users that have entered something in a channel?

Tags: email, list

I would like to send an email to users who have submitted an abstract in the abstracts channel, but leave out users who have not submitted anything.

**what would be the best way to achieve this?**

I personally would just create a template, then have my abstract authors emails listed, and from there, ask my client to copy paste the list into his email app...

something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="abstacts"}
    {embed="_includes/_get_author_email" author_id="{author_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

but I'm sure there's a better way to do this!
any thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking for a more direct way to get the email addresses? Or an automated way to actually send the emails?

Comment: If it's just to get the emails, then a custom query using the query module is probably your best bet

Comment: hi derek, optimally my client would like to have a checkbox, textarea, subject and a send button. or, even better, a checkbox list with all the emails, that he could choose which ones to send to... I guess with the answer from Iain and some template magic I should be able to sort it out! what's the best add-on to send emails from a template? is it postmaster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest method is to use the query module and get the distinct email addresses from all the authors to a particular channel.

This would list all the emails for authors in channel_id 12

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT exp_members.email
            FROM exp_members
            LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles
            ON exp_members.member_id = exp_channel_titles.author_id
            WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = '12' "}
    {email}<br />
{/exp:query}
```

Simply swap out the 12 with the channel ID of your 'abstracts' channel.

Comment: Hi Iian! your query worked like a charm! thanks a lot! I'm impressed!

Comment: @outline4 if Iain's answer solved your problem, make sure to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it.